# Javascript Tag in Header on Select Rails Pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need to include an external javascript file on one page of my Rails App.  I usually put my script tags in the `<HEAD>` tag, but that is controlled by `application.html.erb` and I don't need to include this file except on one page.

Is there a way I can add a javascript file to one page in Rails 3.2?

Comment: It's kind-of a better idea to put your script tags at the end of the `<body>` anyway.  They can go anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
  ....
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>

# your_special_view.html.erb
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "some_script" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your layout, in the head section:

```
<%= yield :javascripts %>
```

Then, in your view, you can do:

```
<%= content_for :javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :some_js %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you want to specify the whole path instead of a symbol:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'path/to/js/file' %>
```

In the above example, the path is relative to app/assets/javascripts/