# Asset Pipleline include jQuery from View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I omitted the line <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> from application.html.erb, so at this time, no javascript whatsoever, but what if i want to have jQuery included after that? And have to do it in the View.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690297/javascript-tag-in-header-on-select-rails-pages

Answer (score 0):

download the jquery file from

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js

add it to the folder your_app/app/assets/javascripts/

then add the following line to your application.html.erb

You have jquery enabled for the app.

If it's for only one page, then add it to the respective view, in the  tag